# R percentage of overlaps

Tags: r, percentage

I've got about 25 datatables. Now I want to find overlaps in the first column in some of the tables and extract them. Furthermore I want to know how many overlaps there are and how many percent. The output should be a table.  Here's an example:

Table1:

```
Gen          Estimate    Std. Error    p-Value
1007_s_at    -0.159699   0.07834       0.04265
1053_at      -0.174647   0.064535      0.0098976
121_at       0.1765678   0.05116854    0.0000657
```

Table2:

```
Gen        Estimate     Std. Error   p-Value
1494_f_at  0.2222467    0.0553653    0.0075838
121_at     0.873683     0.00898737   0.0088378
1316_at    0.098764     0.098456     0.048899
1007_s_at  0.89723      0.5675389    0.00007865
```

Table3:

```
Gen        Estimate     Std.Error    p-Value
1007_s_at  0.0864567    0.8931278    0.005542
121_at     0.2378590    0.0236586    0.00005667
1494_f_at  0.4597023    0.9875357    0.0091234
```

The result should be:

```
Gen      
1007_s_at     
121_at  

Overlapping rate: 20%
```

I tried the foverlaps function, but it didn't work.

I hope someone could help. Thanks!

Update:

This will be my list after merging the first column of all the tables (it will be very long - about 200.000 rows with a mix of 46.000 different genes- so this is just a short example):

```
gene A
gene B
gene C
gene D
gene A
gene E
gene F
gene A
gene C
gene A
gene B
gene D
gene A
gene E
gene B
gene A
gene C
```

So we have 6 times gene A, 3 times gene B, 3 times gene C, 2 times gene D, 2 times gene E and only 1 time gene E. Totally we have 17 genes. That makes 35% for gene A, 18% for gene B and 18% for gene C, 12% for gene D and gene E and 5% for gene F. That is what I am looking for. Maybe it isn't that difficult I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `duplicated()` function for this.

But first you need to merge all the strings of the first colums in one vector. That you do simply with the `c()` function. If your tables are already in one list, or in one dataframe it is easier. May be you also can use a loop, that you don't need to write so much, which depends on the name of your object. It would be useful if I have a minimal working example.

```
merge.first <- c(table1[,1], table2[,1], table3[,1],.... )
```

Than you search for duplicates:

```
position.dup <- duplicated(merge.first)
```

just in case you have more than two duplicates:

```
names(table(merge.first[position.dup])
```

for calculated the number of the duplicates you use the `sum()` function:

```
sum(position.dup)
```

And how you calculate the percentage I don't understand what you mean with this. In your example you have two overlaps by ten rows, that make a percentage of 20% and not 28%. So I unfortunately don't know what you need.

edit:
now I have the same result like you:

```
> merge.vector
 [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "A" "E" "F" "A" "C" "A" "B"
[12] "D" "A" "E" "B" "A" "C"
> round((table(merge.vector) / length(merge.vector) ) * 100)
merge.vector
 A  B  C  D  E  F 
35 18 18 12 12  6
```

this line do what you want:

```
round((table(merge.vector) / length(merge.vector) ) * 100)
```

Comment: Thank you! When I merge the first columns of my different tables, then I have many overlapping genes, but maybe also some that won't overlap. For example I have 300 times gene A (that makes x%) and I have only 20 times gene B (that makes y%). And gene C is only found once, there are no overlaps, that makes 0%. I want to know the percentage of every kind of gene. @and

Comment: Can you post some data which illustrates this point - make it much more easy to support :)

Comment: I hope the example is enough for you :) @and

Comment: jep this is quiet good and i'm happy to assist. Anyway I have the impression you have not so much experience in R. For me things like [this](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/GNU_R) was in the beginning very helpful :)

Comment: That's right! I am a beginner in R and some thinks seem to be quite strange to me. I am happy about your help! Thank you!!!

Comment: your welcome. if nothing else is open don't forget to malk the question as solved.